# Migration of HDDs in RAID 5 from a P410 Controller (Urgent)

Tags: migration, raid5

I'm kind of totally lost right now. 
I have a server with a P410 Controller (256 Mb) and 4 Drives in RAID5. The server don't start :/
I need to find a solution in emergency, but don't know wich one ?

If i take the 4 Drives and put them in another server that have the same P410 controller, will everything be fine ? (no data lost, etc...)

On the worst case, how can i find a way to access to the data ? 
Except getting fired.... ;((

Please help,

Comment: Why is the server not starting?

Comment: Hi Sven, The server was working fine, except the 2nd proc. We bought a new motherboard for it. But when we changed it, nothing happened, the screen remained black, no errors thoughts (no red blinks..etc). So we put back the older motherboard, but nothing happened too :/

Comment: But of course, it doesn't matter if the data on the disks is lost, because you have backups of the data anyway.  Right?

Comment: Well, sure, that was urgent.

Answer (score 2):

You need to designate the Smart Array P410 as the **boot controller**. This can be done in the BIOS or using the **F8** prompt for the Smart Array controller during the POST process.

If you're getting blank screens, make sure your KVM switch and keyboard is healthy.

You mentioned you BOUGHT new system boards. What model of HP server is this? Systems using P410 controllers should still be in warranty. Are you sure you swapped the motherboard properly?

Comment: Yes, but i have no access to the screen? It remains black. 
The server is a DL180 G6. The motherboard is exactly the same as before (same spare number). 
The motherboard have been switched carrefully.

Comment: Anyway, to answer your question, you can move the disks to another server containing a Smart Array controller. Just try to keep the drives in the same order.

Comment: Great ! Thanks ! Does it have an impact if the Controller is a B210i instead of a P410 ?

Comment: Yes, that may not be a good migration... I'm not sure if the B110's featureset is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your power cords connected in the back and that the PMU is connected to the motherboard.  Make sure the CPU is seated properly and that the RAM is all seated properly.  The first thing to do it figure out why it is not turning on at all.  Worst case is that you fried the board when putting the old motherboard back.  Make sure you didnt leave a screw on top of the motherboard or something like that.

Comment: That answer was based on the computer not powering on at all.  If the screen is black but the computer has status lights and fans going, then just check your monitor/KVM connections.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, i found a solution. Evwhite gave me a helpful way with his answer.

This is what i have done, (if that can help someone in extreme case) to do a super fast recovery. That's "kitchen work", the cheapest way, so don't take it as a super-pro solution. 
 - I put the Controller Board P410 on another server, with the SFF-8087 cable connected to the old server drives. 
 - I switch on the old server to give power to the drives.
 - The drives were immediatly accessible by the new server with the P410 in it.
 - I duplicated the data into the new server.
 - Done.

Now, i can figure out, easily, and quitely how to solve this problem with more time. At least the goal is achieve : get the data up and running in a super fastest time.

(in a better world, with suffisant equipment, a replication system like Veeam would have been terrific instead of doing this crazzy stupid work).

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! If this has resolved your issue, please be sure to [mark your answer as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) when you are able.